# Why is my enumeration stopping after first rejection in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, enumeration

Desperate need of help. I am trying to remove arrays from and array of arrays, and I have hit a road block. Essentially, if the first value in the child-array doesn't exist in either position of **any other** child-arrays, then it should be deleted. (presume that the array will be sorted - cause it will be)

```
arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
arr.each_with_index do |inside_array, index|
    if !index.zero?
        # arr.delete(arr[index]) if arr.select {|x| x.include?(inside_array[0])}.count < 2
        # refactored
        arr.reject! {|x| x.include?(inside_array[0])}
    end
end
=> [[0, 1], [4, 5]]
# Why does it stop itterating/enumerating after the first deletion?
# Goal output is [[0, 1]] for this example
```

Similarly, an array such as `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [1, 5]]`, should yield `[[0, 1], [1, 5]]`
-or -
`[[0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 3]]`, should yield `[[0, 1], [0, 3]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tried to modify origin array. That's your problem.

In that cases you need to duplicate it like this:

```
arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
arr.dup.each_with_index do |inside_array, index|
  if !index.zero?
    arr.reject! {|x| x.include?(inside_array[0])}
  end
end

arr #=> [[0, 1]]
```

So just use `dup`

As for the second question (implementation of subarray removal), I suggest this refactoring:

```
def remove_subarray(arr)
  arr.reject { |inside_array| (inside_array & arr.first).empty? }
end

remove_subarray([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]) #=> [[0, 1]]
remove_subarray([[0, 1], [2, 3], [1, 5]]) #=> [[0, 1], [1, 5]]
remove_subarray([[0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 3]]) #=> [[0, 1], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: hmm...  I understand your logic about affecting the origin and needing a duplicate.  But I couldn't get your suggestion to work on my sample data such as `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 5]]`, this yielded `arr => []` - I will accept the answer, because it appears to work in some cases - I think I'll go with if/elsif conditionals to populate a new array instead

Comment: @brian-welch, I've updated the answer. Hope this will helpful